# Which passwords I should put for this MySQL command

Tags: mysql

I have intalled mySQL on my ubuntu 14.04. So the ubuntu's password is "foo" and mySQL password is "bar". Now I inter the below command:

```
mysqladmin -p create servermail
```

and it tells me to inter the password. I try both foo and bar and I got just this message:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'austin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

So what is wrong with my password? what should I inter instead foo and bar?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: `mysqladmin -uroot -p create servermail` and its "foo"

Comment: @Rufinus thank you very much. Is that bar? bar is working.